# Issue using deepcopy with dictionary inside object

Tags: python, dictionary

Reading the documentation, I understood that `copy.deepcopy(obj)` copies recursively any other object inside this one, but when I run:

```
>>> import copy
>>> class SomeObject:
...     a=1
...     b={1:1,2:2}
... 
>>> o1=SomeObject()
>>> o2=copy.deepcopy(o1)
>>> id(o1)
140041523635624
>>> id(o2)
140041523635912
>>> id(o1.b)
30087968
>>> id(o2.b)
30087968
```

It does not seem to be copying the dictionary inside 'o1'. Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong, or how can I get a copy of the dictionary inside the object?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deepcopy only copies **instance attributes**. Your `b` attribute is a class attribute, instead.

Even if you did *not* create a copy but a new instance of `SomeObject` manually, `b` would still be shared:

```
>>> class SomeObject:
...     a=1
...     b={1:1,2:2}
... 
>>> so1 = SomeObject()
>>> so2 = SomeObject()
>>> so1.b is so2.b
True
>>> so1.b is SomeObject.b
True
```

Make `b` an instance attribute:

```
>>> import copy
>>> class SomeObject:
...     a = 1
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.b = {1: 1, 2: 2}
... 
>>> so1 = SomeObject()
>>> so2 = copy.deepcopy(so1)
>>> so1.b is so2.b
False
```

Comment: I see... :/ Do you know how I could do to copy it when calling deepcopy?

Comment: @XNor: you cannot; when creating a copy you are creating a new instance of the same class, the instances still share that class!

Comment: @XNor: If you wanted per-instance attributes, make them instance attributes instead.